# Query inside WITH XMLNAMESPACE clause

Tags: sql-server, xml

is it possible to get some data of the namespaces in the result xml of FOR XML Clause 
from database

e.g.

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri1' as ns1, 
                'uri2' as ns2,
                DEFAULT 'uri2')
SELECT ProductID, 
  Name,
  Color
FROM Production.Product 
WHERE ProductID=316 or ProductID=317
FOR XML RAW ('ns1:Product'), ROOT('ns2:root'), ELEMENTS
```

RESULTS :

```
     <ns2:root xmlns="uri2" xmlns:ns2="uri2" xmlns:ns1="uri1">
   <ns1:Product>
<ProductID>316</ProductID>
<Name>Blade</Name>
  </ns1:Product>
  <ns1:Product>
<ProductID>317</ProductID>
<Name>LL Crankarm</Name>
<Color>Black</Color>
 </ns1:Product>
  </ns2:root>
```

WHAT IF I'D LIKE TO GET THE VALUE OF  FROM INSIDE DATABASE ?

something like this :

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('uri1' as ns1, 
           **(SELECT namespace from tableName)** as ns2,
            DEFAULT 'uri2')
```

Comment: You cannot do this - the values inside the `WITH XMLNAMESPACES(....)` clause have to be string literals.

Comment: i see, so it will be hard coded, Thanks @marc_s

Comment: Yes - it seems you cannot even use SQL variables, either - so yes, you'll have to hard-code those namespaces

Comment: thanks @marc_s , one more question please
what if im using AUTO Mode in FOR XML clause
i can make a prefix for every ELEMENT in the result XML ? 
Thanks

Comment: I don't know right now - that sounds like a good candidate for a separate question! Someone here on Stackoverflow might know / have used that before

Comment: ok,i will ask it and lets see, thx :)

Comment: Your XML result is suspicious. The `Product` element is in `ns1`, but the properties `ProductID`, `Name`, `Color` etc are in the **unnamed** namespace? Are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: im trying to figure out how to add that same prefix to all the attributes too
and that what i asked here  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10811859/add-prefix-to-xml-tag-in-for-xml-auto-mode

Comment: I don't see any reason why you couldn't use dynamic SQL to do this.

Answer (score 0):

This type of thing is possible with dynamic SQL but obviously that has its own issues.  Please read this excellent [article](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html) from Erland Sommarskog on that topic.

```
DECLARE @productId INT = 317
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'WITH XMLNAMESPACES ( ''uri1'' as ns1, ''@yourNamespace'' as ns2, DEFAULT ''uri2'' ) 
SELECT 
    ProductID,  
    Name, 
    Color 
FROM Production.Product  
WHERE ProductID = @productId
FOR XML RAW (''ns1:Product''), ROOT(''ns2:root''), ELEMENTS'

SET @sql = REPLACE( @sql, '@yourNamespace', 'ns2' )

EXEC sp_executesql @sql, N'@productId INT', @productId
```

Re your FOR XML AUTO question, AUTO is driven by the object and column names, so you can take control of this using aliases, eg

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'uri2', 'ns2' AS ns2, 'uri1' AS ns1 )
SELECT 
    ProductID,  
    Name, 
    Color 
FROM Production.Product AS "ns1:productO"
WHERE ProductID = 317
FOR XML AUTO
```

I personally prefer FOR XML PATH for this as you have complete control and everything is explict ( ie you have to specify namespace and element or attribute, rather than it being inferred by AUTO ).

```
;WITH XMLNAMESPACES( DEFAULT 'uri2', 'ns2' AS ns2, 'uri1' AS ns1 )
SELECT 
    ProductID AS "@ProductID",  
    Name AS "@Name", 
    Color AS "@Color"
FROM Production.Product AS "ns1:productO"
WHERE ProductID = 317
FOR XML PATH('ns1:product0')
```

Probably a separate question though ; )

HTH