# add Prefix to XML tag in FOR XML AUTO mode

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I'd like to know if it is possible to add `TAG PREFIX` before every ELEMENT TAG 
in the result of `FOR XML AUTO` mode.

I know it's possible with `RAW` mode but I need to make its as hierarchy as possible xml result

Something like this:

```
       <prefix:attName>
        <prefix:ID>value</prefix:ID>
        <prefix:name>value</prefix:name>
      </prefix:attName>
```

and the query in the `RAW` mode will be like this:

```
SELECT ID, 
      Name,
FROM TableName 
FOR XML RAW ('prefix'), ROOT('prefix:attName'), ELEMENTS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this using Aliases:

```
WITH XMLNAMESPACES ('prefix' AS prefix)
SELECT  ID AS [prefix:ID], 
        Name AS [prefix:Name]
FROM    TableName AS [prefix:attName]
FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('prefix:attName'), ELEMENTS
```

Comment: it works but there is no another solution? 
the query will be something HUGE :D